# Mixed inputs / outputs in liquid transaction

Tags: liquid, confidential-transactions

Can one given liquid transaction be made of a mix of blinded and unblinded inputs and/or outputs?

If for example I have 1 input blinded + 1 input unblinded and then 1 output unblinded, one would be able to find out the value of the blinded input. That would generate privacy risks, right?

Comment: I have not tried this but I think we can have blinded and unblinded inputs for a transaction. If it works as expected then it won't be good for privacy although there are two types of blinding: amount and type. If blinded input was only for hiding type then it should be fine I guess. You can try different things with [elements](https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/releases) and [rawtransaction](https://elementsproject.org/en/doc/0.21.0.0/rpc/) RPCs.